# Cannot install Lubuntu on chromebook

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, chromebook

I've tried installing about 5 times now with the same result, I have a USB key which I've made with the make a boot disk utility thing on linux mint. When I hit install it goes through everything normally then hits an error. ""Installation Failed Bootloader Installation error The bootloader could not be installed. The installation command grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=ubuntu --force returned error code 1."" I have had Lubuntu installed before, I couldn't wipe the drive cause I can't take it out since it's built into the motherboard and if I try to do it through the command line with wipefs it says the drive is in use *and I really don't wanna wipe all the partitions one by one.*

Comment: Have you select the option to erase and install or other?

Comment: I chose to erase the disk, still got the same thing.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I forgot there were different versions. I couldn't find a download for lubuntu x86_64 but my chromebook is x86_64, and for the installer it's called USB Image Writer which was using the amd iso for lubuntu. Whoops..

Comment: ISO is lubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso I got it from lubuntu.me and just downloading the LTS version.